# f# Intersection of lists

Tags: list, f#, intersection

```
let rec mem list x = match list with
                 | [] -> false
                 | head :: tail -> 
                   if x = list.Head 
                   then true
                   else mem list.Tail x
```

The function mem takes a list and a var X as parameter and checks if the list contains the value X and returns true if it does and false if it doesent.

```
let rec intersection list1 list2 = match list1 with
               | head :: tail -> match list2 with 
                     | head :: tail -> if mem list2 list1.Head = true 
                     then (*add the value to a list*) else intersection list1.Tail list2
               | [] -> failwith "Second list is empty"
       | [] -> failwith "First list is empty"
```

I am quite new to F# and the problem i am having right now is i dont know how to construct a list in the (*add the value to a list*) and then add the value to it. I havent tested the code yet since i need to complete this step first in order to not get errors so im not 100% sure on how it works.

I am trying to intersect 2 lists, I know that it does exists functions for this "Set.Intersect list1 list2". The indentation is a bit weird aswell here since i didnt want to get to long of rows but you will probably understand anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most direct way to fix your code is to write something like the code below.

In `mem` function, I just fixed the indentation and change it to use `head` and `tail` that you get from pattern matching rather than accessing them via `list.Head` and `list.Tail` (because doing that is more idiomatic and safer):

```
let rec mem list x = 
  match list with
  | [] -> false
  | head :: tail -> 
    if x = head then true else mem tail x
```

In `intersection`, the trick is to use `head::rest` to build a resulting list when `head` is an element that appears in both lists (and `rest` is the list that you get by applying intersection to the tail recursively). You also do not need to match on `list2` because `mem` handles empty lists fine:

```
let rec intersection list1 list2 = 
  match list1 with
  | head :: tail -> 
      let rest = intersection tail list2
      if mem list2 head then head::rest
      else rest
  | [] -> []
```

This is not super efficient (assuming *n* is the length of `list1` and *m* is the length of `list2`, you may need up to *m*n* steps), but that's probably not the point. Also, `intersection` is not tail-recursive so it will not work on large lists, but that's another - more advanced - functional programming topic.

Finally, the code will also return list that may contain a single element multiple times - but I guess that's fine for you (e.g. `intersection [1;1;1] [1]` returns `[1;1;1]` but if you flip the arguments you'll get just `[1]`)

Answer (score 21):

I like to use the set operators http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353629.aspx
You can use `Set.intersect (Set.ofList list1) (Set.ofList list2) |> Set.toList`

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you are going to need to keep track of the list that is being built up.  The best way to do this is to define a helper function that takes the list being built as a parameter and includes it in the recursive calls

```
let intersection list1 list2 = 
  let rec inner list1 list2 builtList = 
    match list1 with
    | head :: tail -> 
      match list2 with 
      | head :: tail -> 
        if mem list2 list1.Head = true then 
          inner tail list2 (list1.Head :: builtList) 
        else
          inner tail list2 builtList
      | [] -> failwith "Second list is empty"
    | [] -> failwith "First list is empty"
  inner list1 list2 []
```

One other comment is that failing on an empty list is bad practice.  Just treat the empty list as a list with no elements hence no intersection is possible

```
let intersection list1 list2 = 
  let rec inner list1 list2 builtList = 
    match list1 with
    | head :: tail -> 
      if mem list2 list1.Head = true then 
        inner tail list2 (list1.Head :: builtList) 
      else
        inner tail list2 builtList
    | [] -> builtList

  inner list1 list2 []
```

This version works but will end up returning a list that has the elements in the reverse order that they appear in `list1`.  To fix that we can use a callback to build up the list in the correct order

```
let intersection list1 list2 = 
  let rec inner list1 list2 builder = 
    match list1 with
    | head :: tail -> 
      if mem list2 list1.Head = true then 
        inner tail list2 (fun next -> list1.Head :: next)
      else
        inner tail list2 builder
    | [] -> (builder [])

  inner list1 list2 (fun x -> x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am 1000 years late to the party, but in case anyone is having a hard time with this question, the answer in the 1st comment didn't work for me. But, that can always be my fault, I am fairly new to F#. I came up with the following that seems to work fine.
Any comments on improvements are welcome, as my code may be goofy.

ps. at this point I don't want to use built-in operators, as I am doing this for a class.

ps1. I don't want to use `if`, my prof prefers `match` (idk why)

```
let rec intersect =
    function 
    | ([],[]) -> []
    | ([],_) -> []
    | (_,[]) -> []
    | (x::xtail,y::ytail) -> match x=y with
                             | true -> x::intersect(xtail,ytail)
                             | false -> intersect(xtail,y::ytail)
```

Comment: After another 1000 years. 
`let lst1 = [2; 3; 1; 4; 0; 5; 7]                                                         
let lst2 = [2; 3; 7; 8; 9; 0; 1]
let lst3 = intersect (lst1,lst2)`

Gives => `val lst3: int list = [2; 3; 7]`    // 1 and 0 are missing